# Can we get users of a particular project in openstack?

Tags: openstack

I want users in the projects and there roles to find that who is the admin of that project.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command :

```
openstack user list --project <name or ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

To find all of the users with any roles in a project:

```
openstack role assignment list --name --project <name or id>
```

(The role that corresponds to the administrator is going to depend on how you have configured the roles and their associated permissions.  From Rocky onwards, "admin" is the default role name for administrator privileges.)

Comment: You can filter for a specific role using the `--role` flag.

Comment: Correct.  If you know what role you are looking for.